# Making blocks visible/invisible using javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is my code.

```
var i = 0;
var submenues = document.getElementsByClassName("submenu");
var click = 1;

function submenuvisible() {
  if (click == 1) {
    for (i; i < submenues.length; i++) {
      submenues[i].style.display = "block";
    }
    click = 2;
    return;
  }
  if (click == 2) {
    for (i; i < submenues.length; i++) {
      submenues[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    click = 1;
    return;
  }
}
```

Though when i `onclick=submenuvisible()` it works only 1 time. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is in your for loops.

Where you have: `for (i; i < submenues.length; i++) {`

You need to reset the variable `i` to `0` at the beginning of the for loops.

`for (i = 0; i < submenues.length; i++) {`

If you don't reset it, then `i` will remain at the same value it was after the first time you run your function. You could improve your code further by not making `i` a global variable, but overall, I hope this explains your issue.

Comment: Better yet, remove the global declaration and use `for (let i=0; ... )` to keep it scoped to the loop.

Comment: WOW it works than u very much, though it doesn't make sense) c# doesn't need to reset variables

Comment: If it doesn't make sense then I have failed to explain/help you properly. @TylerRoper had a great suggestion in their comment and maybe can help me improve my answer.

Comment: o just didnt read ur coment whole or u updated it, i get it now, second time i=4(arrays length), i should have used different variable a noob mistake, though i am a noob